# Sub-additivity for $\limsup \limits_{n\to\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, and prove the following assertion: $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leqslant \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$$ provided the sum on the right is not of the form $\infty-\infty$.

**Proof:** Let $\alpha:=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\beta:=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$.
Cases $(\alpha,\beta)=(+\infty,+\infty), (c,+\infty)$ are obvious.

By definition $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n:=\inf \limits_{k\geqslant 1}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k} a_i=\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i$. Since $a_j+b_j\leqslant \sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i$ for $j\geqslant k$ then $\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}(a_i+b_i)\leqslant \sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i$. Since $\{\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}(a_i+b_i)\}_{k\geqslant 1}$ and $\{\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i\}_{k\geqslant 1}$ are decreading sequences then: $$\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}(a_i+b_i)\leqslant  \lim \limits_{k\to \infty}(\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i)$$ But $\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}(\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i)=\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}a_i+\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k}b_i$ if $(\alpha,\beta)$ has the following forms: $(-\infty,-\infty), (\alpha,-\infty), (\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}^1$.

Sorry if this topic is repeated since I saw the same topic in MSE but I would like to know is my proof true? Would be very grateful for any comment\remark.

Can anyone check my proof please?

Comment: It's correct and elegant. However, one must also require that $a_n + b_n$ is never (or at most finitely often, since we're looking at $\limsup$ we can ignore finitely many undefined terms in the sequence, but not infinitely many) of the form $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thanks a lot for checking! But I guess that we don't consider the case $\infty-\infty$ at general.