# Help understanding $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

I know there's a proof somewhere on here but I just can't seem to understand it.
Can anyone give me an exemple why this is true. In my head, I always see it as equal... it's like I take the supremum from the set $A$ and I take an supremum of the set $B$ and I add it up... where I'm I wrong?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Here's you can find smth useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812070/sub-additivity-for-limsup-limits-n-to-infty

Comment: a_n+b_n<= limsup(a_n)+limsup(b_n) . limsup {a_n+b_n}<=limsup {(limsup(a_n)+limsup(b_n)}=limsupa_n+limsupb_n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$, so we have this:
\begin{align}
(a_n : n=1,2,3,\ldots) & = \left( \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} -1, & 1, & -1, & 1, & -1, & 1, & \ldots \end{array} \right) \\
(b_n : n=1,2,3,\ldots) & = \left( \begin{array}{rrrrrrrr} 1, & -1, & 1, & -1, & 1, & -1, & \ldots \end{array} \right)
\end{align}
Then $a_n+b_n=0$ for all $n$, so $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n) = 0$.

But $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = 1+1=2$.

That shows how the two sides can fail to be equal.  Why the opposite inequality cannot hold is another question; maybe I'll come back and add that later.

Comment: when $a$ and $b$ are correlated, it's possible to get less

Answer (score 2):

[Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) gave an example when the two sides are not equal. I will provide a proof of the inequality in the OP. First, we recall the definition of the limit superior:

$$ \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m $$

Now, we prove the statement. We have that

$$ \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n + b_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m + b_m \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sup_{m \geq n} a_m + \sup_{m \geq n} b_m \right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m + \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} b_m = \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to \infty} b_n $$

The key inequality is $ \sup_{m\geq n} (a_m + b_m) \leq \sup_{m\geq n} a_m + \sup_{m\geq n} b_m $. This inequality holds because the right hand side is clearly an upper bound for $ a_m + b_m $, therefore it is greater than or equal to the LHS by definition of the least upper bound.

Note that this also tells us *when* equality might fail. For another example, you may consider the following:

$$ \limsup_{x\to \infty} (\sin(x) + \cos(x)) = \sqrt{2} $$
$$ \limsup_{x\to \infty} \sin(x) + \limsup_{x\to \infty} \cos(x) = 2 $$

The problem, as stated by [Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard), is that $ \sin(x) $ and $ \cos(x) $ do not attain their supremum values at the same points.

Comment: Your proof is predicated on the statement "This inequality holds because the right hand side is clearly an upper bound ..."  I suggest considering expanding on this.  ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 1):

It is not like taking the supremum of $A$ and the supremum of $B$ and adding them to obtain the supremum of $A+B$, because the values in $A$ and $B$ are indexed by a natural number $n$, and the supremum for $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily attained at the same index $n$. Hence the sum of the suprema is only an upper bound for the sum of elements with the same index.